# Java byte array to Float conversion in c#

Tags: java, c#, udp, byte

I am **sending a UDP packet from java to C# over the network**. 
The packet received succesfully. I am sending some values in a byte array. the Byte array is in Little Endian format. so C# can read it directly without converting to Big Endian. the first 2 bytes is a short value, which I read successfully in C# with

```
 public short getShort(byte[] bytes,int index)
 {
    short val = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes,index);
    return val;
}
```

then there are seven float values to read

i try to read them with the

```
public float floatConversion(byte[] bytes,int index)
{
    float myFloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes,index);
    return myFloat;
}
```

but it gives wrong values. 
here is the main of c#

```
        UdpClient client = null;
        try
        {
            client = new UdpClient(8888);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        IPEndPoint server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast,8888);
        byte[] packet = client.Receive(ref server);
        Console.WriteLine(packet.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(getShort(packet,0));
        Console.WriteLine(getFloat(packet, 3));
        Console.Read();
```

here is the java code which I am sending Packet from

```
 DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    short cc = 9999;
    float   x=66.2342f,
            y=44.6133f,
            z=99.4424f,
            rX=22.7789f,
            rY=11.9911f,
            rZ=99.1254f;
    float anim=96.1133f;
    ByteBuffer buffer =ByteBuffer.allocate(30);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    buffer.putShort(cc);
    buffer.putFloat(x);
    buffer.putFloat(y);
    buffer.putFloat(z);
    buffer.putFloat(rX);
    buffer.putFloat(rY);
    buffer.putFloat(rZ);
    buffer.putFloat(anim);
    System.out.println(buffer.array().length);
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer.array(),buffer.array().length,InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2"),8888);
    socket.send(packet);
```

what is wrong in this , and how can I fix it? Thank You.

Comment: Where is the code where you update the index when you call the c# methods?

Comment: im sorry , Added it :D

Comment: I think I found the problem , in main i have just mistaken the index